# Printing data from Android phones to the printer via computer

Tags: printing, bluetooth

I can transfer data (images, string) from android to computer via bluetooth.
This computer is connected to the printer (Brother MFC- 7360) by USB port. 
How do I do for the printer to print received image automatically when the computer receives the image?

I heard that when we install driver of the printer into the computer. There are the windows servers running in the background to listen printing event from computer. But I have no knowledge about that.

Can anyone helps me? Thanks in advance.
P/S: Are there any solution for generic printer?

Comment: I don't know why this was migrated here. This would seem to be a computer hardware question rather than one about Android. That said, have you looked at Google Cloud Print?

Answer (score 1):

The method your are describing doesn't seem possible, you are trying to have your photos printed as they arrive to your computer!

What you can do is to print data directly from your android device to a printer:

1. Print directly from an Android device with the right Wi-Fi or Bluetooth printer that are available to the device.
2. Print to a printer connected to a computer, by using the Google's free Cloud Print technology:

   > ## [Google Cloud Print](http://www.google.com/cloudprint/learn/)
   >
   > Google Cloud Print is a new technology that connects your printers to the web. Using Google Cloud Print, you can make your home and work printers available to you and anyone you choose, from the applications you use every day. Google Cloud Print works on your phone, tablet, Chromebook, PC, and any other web-connected device you want to print from.

   [image]

   ### Requirements:

   You will need to have a computer where the printer is connected to, with Google Chrome installed and connected to the Google Cloud Print service, in order to have it receiving files from your devices.

   - Printer Connected and installed on your OS;
   - Google Chrome Installed;
   - Cloud Print set up on Google Chrome;
   - Logged on with the same user as your device.

   ### Setup the computer:

   1. Launch Google Chrome;
   2. Access the menu (icon in the upper-right corner);
   3. select "Settings";
   4. On the Settings page, scroll down until your see "Show advanced settings..." and click it;
   5. Keep scrolling down until you find the "Google Cloud Print" section:

      The available options may vary, but usually you will see a "Add printers" or a "Manage print settings" button.
      The first will add your installed printers to the list. The second will allow you to see what printers are there.

   ### Start Printing from your Android device:

   To start printing what you want you'll need to install the following app:

   #### [Cloud Print](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.cloudprint&hl=en)

   > **Description**
   >   With Cloud Print for Android you can:
   >
   > - Print from any compatible Android device to any Google Cloud Print connected printer
   > - Share a picture or a document from apps like Gallery directly to Cloud Print
   > - Track the status of your print jobs
   >
   > Printing from Android has never been easier.

   [image: Google Cloud Print screenshot]

   You open the document, photo, etc on your device and access the "Share" options, where you will find the "Cloud Print" option.

---

## Links:

- [Cloud Print - Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.cloudprint&hl=en)
- [Google Cloud Print Homepage](http://www.google.com/cloudprint/learn/)
- [PCWorld - Answer Line: How to print from Android](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2027751/answer-line-how-to-print-from-android.html)
- [TabletPC Review - How to Print from a Tabet: Google Cloud Print & Android Solutions](http://www.tabletpcreview.com/default.asp?newsID=3026&news=apple%20ipad%20print%20android%20tablet&p=2)
- [LifeHacker - Add Wireless Printing to Your Android Phone with Cloud Print](http://lifehacker.com/5775462/cloud-print-sends-web-pages-images-and-files-to-your-printer-through-chrome--dropbox)

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Pint is what you need. It easily connects your normal printers to the cloud and saves them in your cloud printers list. You can the print any document from anywhere in the world by just logging in to your Google account and giving the print command from Google Drive or Google Chrome.

For Android there is an official app by Google: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.cloudprint